# Höfliches Ersuchen mit "ruhig"

Tags: usage, grammaticality

Wird es in der Alltagssprache als zu gehoben (oder gar altmodisch) bezeichnet, wenn man eine höfliche Bitte mit "ruhig" sanfter macht? Zum Beispiel:

> "Nehmen Sie ruhig Platz!"
>
> "Geben Sie mir ruhig Bescheid!"

Comment: Nein, wird es nicht.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ich (Jahrgang '85) finde den Ausdruck weder gehoben noch altmodisch. Wenn du allerdings Bedenken in diese Richtung hast, kannst du ruhig stattdessen das Wort "gerne" verwenden:

> Nehmen sie gerne Platz!
>
> Sie können mir gerne Bescheid geben!

Comment: "Ruhig" finde ich auch weder gehoben noch altmodisch. "Gerne" hingegen schon ein wenig.

Answer (score 5):

Aber Aufpassen mit der Ironie! Denn wenn Du **nach** dem Betreten eines Zimmers hörst

> *"Kommen Sie ruhig herein"*

weißt Du, dass Du besser hättest warten sollen, bis Du dazu aufgefordert wirst. Zu solchen Spitzen eignet sich das Wörtchen "*ruhig*" ganz vorzüglich.